# Как настроить мониторинг inodes в Datadog?

Tags: мониторинг, inode

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать custom check, например inodes и посылать alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно настроить монитор на метрику `system.fs.inodes.free` и сделать на её основании алерт.